# Camel file input reads same file continuously even with given noop=true

Tags: java, spring, routes, apache-camel, camel-ftp

The camel file component is reading the same file continuously and not detecting other files.

I have a camel route as,

```
<camelContext trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="file:C:/Books/input_dir?noop=true"/>
        <dynamicRouter>
            <method ref="fileRouter" method="routeFiles"></method>
        </dynamicRouter>
    </route>
</camelContext>
<bean id="fileRouter" class="org.test.demo.DynamicRouter"/>
```

and Router as,

```
public class DynamicRouter {
    public String routeFiles(Exchange exchange){
        final String fileName = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME_ONLY);
        System.out.println("FILENAME: "+fileName);
        if(fileName.contains("survival")){
            return "file:C:/Books/output_dir";
        }else {
            return "file:C:/Books/target_dir";
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever a file say **beahomelist**  is dropped into `C:/Books/input_dir` folder it reads the first file and never stops as the log below

> FILENAME: beahomelist FILENAME: beahomelist FILENAME: beahomelist
>   FILENAME: beahomelist FILENAME: beahomelist FILENAME: beahomelist
>   FILENAME: beahomelist FILENAME: beahomelist....

and doest not detect any further files put in the same folder. Even though noop=true is given it happens so. Please provide some suggestions on this. I am using camel version: 2.13.0

Comment: any suggestion on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation about dynamic router eip, see that Beware! box in the top

- http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router

Though it looks like you should use "dynamic to" instead of dynamic router, see this FAQ

- http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

So just use

```
  <recipientList>
        <method ref="fileRouter" method="routeFiles"></method>
    </recipientList>
```

Comment: Thanks Claus. It helped me to understand and resolve the issue